# Spring Tool Suite : Hello World error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z

Tags: spring-boot

> When I try to run a Simple Hello World Program in STS(Spring Starter
>   Project) I am getting the following error. I am using Spring Tool Suite 
>   Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE.  I started with file new Spring Starter Project and >tried to run using Spring boot App.

```
[2m2016-04-13 13:22:34.364[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m864[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.Demo1Application            [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Demo1Application on Chinmay with PID 864 (C:\Users\Chinmay\Documents\newStsWorkspace\demo1\target\classes started by Chinmay in C:\Users\Chinmay\Documents\newStsWorkspace\demo1)
[2m2016-04-13 13:22:34.368[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m864[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.Demo1Application            [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2016-04-13 13:22:34.468[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m864[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@10b48321: startup date [Wed Apr 13 13:22:34 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-13 13:22:35.476[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m864[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z
    at org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:56) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:182) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getFromFactory(BeanTypeRegistry.java:338) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:171) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:139) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:113) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Demo1Application.main(Demo1Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

[2m2016-04-13 13:22:35.543[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m864[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/Documents/newStsWorkspace/demo1/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Chinmay/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar]
```

[image]

> **DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you show you project structure and directories. Config files too??

Comment: `StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer` requires Java 8 and, by default, Spring Framework will only use it when it's running on Java 8 (it's only added to `PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer` when a class that's new in Java 8 (`java.lang.reflect.Executable`) is on the class path). What version of Java are you using? I would guess 7, in which case we'll need some more information to figure out what's going on. Can you share a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am Using jdk 1.8.0

Comment: Andy and Karan I have added the files and the directory structure. Thanks

Comment: That's very strange. `java.lang.reflect.Parameter` is new in Java 8, yet it looks like the class has been loaded but that the `isNamePresent()` method is missing. Can you run with `-verbose:class` as a VM argument and see where `java.lang.reflect.Parameter` is being loaded from?